# Method returning any type of DbSet<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi how can I return any type of DbSet? I can't specific the type because I want to make my code thiner.

I tried this but i get errors about converting.

```
public DbSet<Type> GetDbSet(string category)
    {
        switch (category)
        {
            case "Processors":
                return context.Processors;
            case "Graphic cards":
                return context.GPUs;
            default: return context.Users;
        }
    }
```

I need it to thin the code

before:

```
    public Object GetProduct(int productId) //Returns product with his specific class by his id
    {
        var productDetails = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == productId);
        switch (productDetails.Category)
        {
            case "Processors":
                return context.Processors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Product_ID == productId);
            case "Graphic cards":
                return context.GPUs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Product_ID == productId);
            /*And more*/
            default: return new Object();
        }
```

after:

```
        public Object GetProduct(int productId) //Returns product with his specific class by his id
        {
            var productDetails = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == productId);
            return GetDbSet(productDetails.Category).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x.GetType().GetProperty("Product_ID").GetValue(x) == productDetails.ProductID);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your return type `DbSet<Type>` to `IQueryable<object>`.